# Handle exception in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've create new attribute and in the logic I've some exception
My question is: how should I handle it in the **controller** and pass it to the view?
In the code below I throw the exception, how should I move it to the view?

This is the attribute in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[CheckToken]
public JsonResult Edit(Roles role)
{
    ...
}
```

This is the attribute

```
public class CheckToken : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    ....

    catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
    {
        throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("token not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks to me that you're returning an error to user using http status 200 (OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of throwing exception..u can do like as :-

```
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
{
   filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("Antiforgery", "token not found");
}
```

and use Routevalues in ur jsonresult as :

```
[HttpPost]
[CheckToken]
public JsonResult GroupEdit(Roles role)
{
  ViewData["Message"] = RouteData.Values["Antiforgery"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks,how should I get the data from the ViewData["Message"] ?

Comment: it depends on ur requirement @shopiaT u can put this viewdata value in a variable and return json(variable name,jsonresult.allowget) or u can also directly use viewdata value in jquery as '@ViewData["Message"]'

Comment: Do you mean something like this    if (ViewData["Message"] != null) return Json(objRes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ?

Comment: return Json(new { objRes=ViewData["Message"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 2):

From the book [CLR Via C#](http://books.google.com.vn/books/about/CLR_via_C.html?id=QMdCf_mm55cC&redir_esc=y), there is an advice on exceptions handling:

> **Don’t CatchEverything**
>
> A ubiquitous mistake made by developers who
>   have not been properly trained on the proper use of 
>   exceptions is to use catchblocks too often and
>   improperly. When you catch an exception, you’re  stating that you
>   expected this exception, you understand why it occurred, and you know
>   how to deal  with it.

We should catch exceptions only when we know how to **recover our application state** from that exception.

In your code, you catch the exception without doing anything than just re-throwing it. This is just not necessary. And be aware that when you re-throw the exception, the CLR resets its starting point for the exception.

```
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
{
    throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("token not found"); // CLR thinks this is where exception originated.
}
```

In your case, I **would not handle the exception** and pass it to the view. I will just let the execution stop and handle it inside a global exception filter to **return an error** to the user with **correct http status code** (for example: we should not return an error page with status 200) and may optionally log an error to DB for further analysis.

For information how to implement global exception filter: http://forums.asp.net/t/1848242.aspx?How+to+implement+global+error+handling+in+ASP+NET+Web+API